# Runtime Error with libstdc++.so.6, libc.so.6, and GLIB

Tags: java, c++, linker, runtime-error, shared-libraries

having a runtime issue with GLIB stuff. 
I needed to use different libraries than the ones that are default in /usr/lib64 and /lib64, so I compiled my library and used patchelf to add the newer libraries which contained the missing GLIBs. After patchelf, I used `ldd` to check my library:

```
$ ldd libMyLib.so
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffde5ff000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007ff91b4e9000)
        libasn1per.so => /path/to/new/lib/libasn1rt.so (0x00007fde2373a000)
        libasn1rt.so => /path/to/new/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fde2345d000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /path/to/new/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ff91b20b000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff91af86000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ff91ad70000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff91ab53000)
        libc.so.6 => /path/to/new/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff91a7a3000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00000036b5e00000)\
```

```
libMyLib.so: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by path/to/libMyLib.so)
```

Sometimes it gets libc.so.6 errors instead:

```
/lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /path/to/libMyLib.so)
```

However, when my app is running, (Java app using `System.loadLibrary("MyLib")`) I get the above error. The error seems to show that it's still looking at the old version of libstdc++.so.6. Is there a reason for this? Also, editing LD_LIBRARY_PATH doesn't work. Based on other posts, it's because of certain files requiring different versions of the libraries. I really thought the patchelf would work especially due to the ldd output. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm... Why use different versions of library?

Comment: @Smankusors The place I compile my files is not the same environment that I run them in. Sadly this is not in my control.

Comment: I think you should send in source code form and then compile it on the destination. Is the compiler available at that destination?